# How to set a 0..* relationship in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationships, object-relationships

I have the next code for two classes:

```
public class Object
{
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }

    public int Object2ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Object2 Object2 { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public int Object2ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Object> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

I know that with Entity Framework, this will create a one-to-many relationship, but what I want to know, is how to transform this to a zero-to-many relationship.

I'm new to Entity Framework and I couldn't find any direct answer around.

Comment: It's still one to many relationship, the difference only either to have required Principal or optional Principal on Dependent.

Comment: I agree, I can't see how you can have a 0 to anything relationship if there's 0 of something then it can't relate to anything.

Comment: Just a fyi, normal nomenclature you don't use `∞` as it is a special character and some systems may not like the Unicode. Normally you would express it as `0..*` and that is what you will see in most documentation refrences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a 0-to-many relationship in Entity Framework, have the foreign key be nullable.

```
public int? Object2ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do I need to set 

public virtual Object2 Object2 { get; set; }

As nullable too, or only the key?

Comment: No. As a class, Object2 can already be set to null if needed.

Comment: @user3552621 It's nullable "by nature". By the way, you don't NEED to have Object2ID in class Object.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is by using Fluent API:

```
public class YouDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<Object2>
            .HasMany(o1 => o1.Objects)
            .WithOptional(o2 => o2.Object2);

        base.OnModelCreating(mb);
    }
}
```